# Linux shell script to search and delete line with respect to todays date with format mm/dd/yyy

Tags: linux, shell, search, sed

Linux shell script to search and delete line with respect to todays date with format mm/dd/yyy.

Example: to be removed 11/08/2016

Input :

```
joba_name_11   11/02/2016 06:30:01  -----                RU 5359761/1
joba_name_11   11/07/2016 06:30:01  -----                RU 5359761/1
joba_name_11   11/08/2016 06:30:01  -----                RU 5359761/1
```

Output :

```
joba_name_11   11/02/2016 06:30:01  -----                RU 5359761/1
joba_name_11   11/07/2016 06:30:01  -----                RU 5359761/1
```

Syntax used :

```
$TODAY = 11/08/2016
sed -i 's/$TODAY/d' < $inputfile  > $outputfile
```

Error:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 3: unknown command: `/'

Comment: I don't see a question - have a look at [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Grep to the rescue - use `grep -v` to show all lines **not** containing a pattern. Combined with `date` (with format `%m/%d/%Y` to get your date format) you get a oneliner:

```
grep -v `date +%m/%d/%Y` < infile > outfile
```

(Backticks in bash are used to execute a program, in this case you're supplying `grep` with the output of `date`.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the use of sed is essential:

```
TODAY=$(date +"%m/%d/%Y")
sed "\|$TODAY|d" inputfile > outputfile
```

Note that it says the same as `/pattern/d`, but because the `$TODAY` contains slashes, its better to choose a different separator - in this case `|`.